# Find all integers $n$ such $1^n+2^n+3^n$ is square.

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $n$ such $$1^n+2^n+3^n$$ is square.

I found this only  postive solution  $n=3$

because $$1^3+2^3+3^3=6^2$$

Now I solve when $n$ is even,then $1+2^n+3^n$ can't square,because

if $n$is even,we have
$$1+2^n+3^n\equiv 2\pmod 3$$ so this case can't square

But for $n$ is odd?

this problem is old?because I think this is interesting problem.

Comment: More general: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2372522/42969

Comment: Interesting yes, but not new. Several similar posts are here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740505/solve-x2-2n-3n-6n-over-positive-integers?noredirect=1).

Comment: That doesn't really count as "more general" since it has a $\forall n$ in it, @MartinR

Comment: @DietrichBurde,this is different my problem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, it is not "more general". However, this one at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1781691p11743171) is more general.

Comment: msexkac, no it is no so different. You can use similar methods to solve it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You are right, I missed that.

Comment: Another variant is [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h486898p2728409). And more ideas are in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484545/when-is-2n-3n-6n-a-perfect-square?noredirect=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I use  your first link,if $n=2k+1$,then $1+2^{2k+1}+3^{2k+1}\equiv 0\pmod 4$,so then how to do this case ,and $n=2k$, then $1+4^k+9^k=x^2$,also not easy do it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde,you link the last I have post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382549/find-all-intgers-a-b-c-such-that-a-cdot-4nb-cdot-6nc-cdot-9n-is-a-perfe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the more general equation
$$
3^a+2^b+1=y^2
$$
by considering it modulo
$$
2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13.
$$
This was done by Leitner in paper in JTNB in 2011; the only solutions are with
$$
(a,b) = (0,1), (1,5) \mbox{ and } (3,3).
$$

Comment: We often get   questions  for which one needs to know when  an integer   sequence, either $x_{n+3} = a x_{n+2} + b x_{n+1} + c x_n$  or   $x_{n+2} = a x_{n+1} + b x_{n}$  is a square. There were early articles for, say, square Fibonacci numbers. Is there material to read on this?   I have Mordell Diophantine Equations and similar books.   $\; \; \; \; $  Will $\; \; \; \; $ $\; \; \; \; $

Comment: well, this one ( the original question)  would be $x_{n+3} = 6 x_{n+2} - 11 x_{n+1}  + 6 x_n $

Comment: This OP's earlier question, with a "bounty,"  shares the sequence aspect:

Comment: In general, it's really not obvious whether or not a polynomial-exponential equation will have an elementary local solution. By way of example, the apparently similar equation $6^a+2^b+1=y^2$ is currently unsolved. Somewhat general statements about finiteness can sometimes be deduced from the Subspace theorem. The various books/papers of Zannier and Corvaja-Zannier are likely the best references.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n\geq 4$
taking mod 16,
$1^n+2^n+3^n\equiv 1+3^n\equiv 4,10,12,2$
4 is the only quadratic residue mod 16, so $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$
taking mod 9,
$1^n+2^n+3^n\equiv 1+2^n\equiv 3,5,0,8,6,2$
0 is the only quadratic residue mod 9, so $n\equiv 3\pmod{6}$
$n\equiv 9\pmod{12}$
taking mod 13,
$1^n+2^n+3^n\equiv 1+2^9+3^9\equiv 7$
7 is not a quadratic residue mod 13, contradiction.
check $n=1,2,3$ to conclude $n=3$

note: one can also take mod 7 to get $n\equiv 3\pmod{6}$.